# WebSphereMQ with HermesJMS

Tags: ssl, jms, soapui, ibm-mq

I use WebSphereMQ v7.1 and HermesJMS v1.14 SoapUI.
I set up everything to connect this apps without SSL and they work fine. 
The problem is, when I try to connect with SSL. I set below params:

```
SSLCipherSuite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
channel, hostName, port, queueManager,
transportType: 1
```

and in hermes.bat I added trustStore and keystore.
In WMQ I have set: TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US on channel. On this page-> http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/ja34740_.htm
I see that I match CipherSpec and CipherSuite correct.

What is wrong?

**UPDATE**

Below error from Hermes

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel 'channel1'. [3=channel1] 
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment
(RemoteConnection.java:4322) 
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.receiveTSH
(RemoteConnection.java:2902) 
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.initSess
(RemoteConnection.java:1440) 
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.connect
(RemoteConnection.java:1115) 
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnectionPool.getConnection
(RemoteConnectionPool.java:350) 
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1599)
```

On this page -> http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614686 I find that solution for this problem is:

> Ensure that there is a cipher suite set on the client matching the
>   cipher spec on the queue manager's server connection channel.

but as I mentioned earlier I matched CipherSpec and CipherSuite correct.

Comment: Please add the error reported in the queue manager error log to your question details.

Answer (score 0):

Are using an Oracle JRE/JDK?  I had the same issue and wrote about it here: http://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=3074

The simplest solution is to use IBM's JRE/JDK.

Comment: I had jdk 1.7_55. I changed it to IBM J9 VM 1.5.0 but it stil doesn't work.